# Should I keep variables used only in one class method local or declare them as class properties?

Tags: php, oop

I've been wondering if a class property is instantiated and used only in one class method should it be a class property at all or should it just be a local variable accessible to that class method only?

For example, should I keep a variable only used in one method as a local variable like this:

```
class myClass
{
    public function myMethod()
    {
        $_myVariableUsedOnlyOnce = "Hello World";
        echo $_myVariableUsedOnlyOnce;
    }
}
```

Or should I make the variable a private class property like this:

```
class myClass
{
    private $_myVariableUsedOnlyOnce;

    public function myMethod()
    {
        $this->_myVariableUsedOnlyOnce = "Hello World";
        echo $this->_myVariableUsedOnlyOnce;
    }
}
```

Which approach "smells"? What are the benefits to making all method variables class properties other than when I need to print_r() the entire object for debugging purposes?

Thanks

Comment: If you're certain it will only be used once, make it local to the method.  Otherwise, you're correct to make it private.  _Unless_ you need the value of that variable to persist between calls of that method, in which it  would at least need to be `static` in the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need it to have persistence across function calls, a class property would be best so that it moves around as the object does. You also might want to use it for other reasons in future in other functions. However, it does add overhead.

Generally, the class should have some real-world analogue, so if your variable corresponds to something that makes sense e.g. a person class has a $height, then it belongs as a class property. Otherwise, if it's just a part of the internal calculations of a method, then it doesn't really belong attached to the class e.g. a person does not have a $shoelaceIterator or whatever.

I'd argue that a confusing object design would be more of a smell than a potentially small memory overhead (although this depends on how big the variable is).

Answer (score 2):

These local variables are not properties of your object.

They are not defining your object, then they should not be declared as private member.

Answer (score 0):

First I would ask if you really need the variable/property at all if you are only using it once. As for which one "smells", a property is stored in memory for the entire life of the object whereas the variable is only in memory until the method finishes executing.

Comment: Obviously that was just a simple example and I would be doing more with the variable in the method than just echoing "Hello World". But thanks, I see the benefit in terms of memory allocation.

Comment: It's not just memory allocation, as "zedat" has pointed out it's speed as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a variable outside the method, it should not be any property of the class. Moreover, accessing local variables is faster.

Answer (score 0):

In a pure design approach I would suggest you to make your choice according to what the attribute/property is supposed to model.

In pure performance terms, having one static attribute is better because memory space won't be allocate with each instance of the class.